# Conver radiobutton to a char

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, radio-button

I have three radio buttons. Please see the image.

[image: radio buttons]

I define a variable

```
char temp;
```

What I want is

If "Male" is selected then

```
temp = "M";
```

If "Female" is selected then

```
temp = "F";
```

If "Both" is selected then

```
temp = "B".
```

My unfinished code:

```
temp = Convert.ToChar(this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked));
```

Thanks for advice.

**EDIT:**
The controls are in a groupbox. In the debug mode. I got an error.

> ?groupBox4.Controls.OfType()
>   {System.Linq.Enumerable.OfTypeIterator}
>       source: null
>   And
>   ?groupBox4.Controls.OfType().FirstOrDefault(r=>r.Checked).Text
>   Expression cannot contain lambda expressions

**EDIT 2:**
See the image. Run code get the exception.
[image: error]

Comment: `this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked).Text[0]`

Comment: @Love - When you say "In the debug mode" do you mean one of the debug windows (immediate?, output?) or did you just get an exception?

See if this [solves your problem](http://osmirnov.net/posts/expression-cannot-contain-lambda-expressions/)

Comment: You cannot use Lambda expressions in the immediate window (See the link I added in my comment above). But I don't understand why this has any effect on your question or on the answers... Run the code without trying to process it in the immediate window and check if it works.

Comment: I'm guessing it happens when no radiobutton is checked? I updated my answer below....

Comment: I did check a button but I found rb=null. It means that something wrong in the code. Maybe FirstOrDefault???

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, then this is based on your (not-so-recommended) assumption that each RadioButton's **Name** starts with a different letter.

```
temp = Convert.ToChar(this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked).Name.Substring(0, 1));
```

**Edit:**
Same assumption but based on the *Text* property instead of the *Name* property

```
    temp = Convert.ToChar(this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked).Text.Substring(0, 1));
```

**Edit2:** (Based on OPs Edit - Checking that a Checked RadioButton exists):

```
RadioButton rb = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);

if (rb != null)
{
    temp= rb.Text[0];
}
```

Comment: You could also set the `Tag` property and retreive that.

Comment: It is windows form application. There is no ClientID. Sorry.

Comment: @Love then you can use Name instead of ClientId... (Updated the code).


The Text option will work in both projects.

As I said, I'm still not sure if this is exactly what you need...

Comment: You should limit further to only controls in the GroupBox, otherwise you'll find the first checked radio button on the entire form (which could be something completely different). Also, be sure to check that a radio button is actually checked, otherwise you'll get a null reference exception calling `Text`: `grpGender.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked)`

Comment: @Love - on the code that I wrote you're getting that error? Please update your question with your updated code

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(r => r.Checked).FirstOrDefault();
```